# JFrame to Window class

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe

i want to know which this line code it really true or is there a better way?
can any one help me?

```
JFrame jframe=new JFrame()
Window window;
jframe.setUndecorated(true);


window=(Window)jframe; //is this line true?
```

thank you.

Comment: What result did you get when when you tried it?  BTW - a 'better way' to do what exactly?

Comment: @Andrew i was used AWTUtilites library, the method setWindowOpacity is work well but setWindowShape does not work.

Comment: I wrote that assignment, actually this way

window=jframe;

and there is no problem at all. But what do you want to do? When working with Swing, you usually use Swing componenets all the time. Why do you need Window?

Comment: @mahdi what is your general goal?

Comment: @reporter and @Jav_Rock I told my goal to Andrew. I was used AWTUtilites library, the method setWindowOpacity is work well but setWindowShape does not work

Comment: would suggest reading some introductory textbook on OO - if you don't understand the very basics of inheritence and which types can be used where, you'll get lost in java/Swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's true but you don't need the cast. java.swing.JFrame is a child class of java.awt.Window so it's ok. And I can't find a reason why a method applied to your Window variable wouldn't apply to a JFrame variable. It's not supposed to happen as Java only uses late binding for method calls.

Try to review your code, to check if you import the right classes, because I think you're misunderstanding something.

Comment: i am using AWTUtilities library,  the method setWindowOpacity(Window window, float opacity) is work well but setWindowShape(Window, Sahpe) does not work

Comment: Ok sorry, I understand what you do now. Then the answer is: Yes, the line is correct. If the method doesn't work, it might be because your system doesn't support this functionnality. What about trying your code on another machine ? Also next time, write down the exception text in your question, because it's hard to understand what you mean. Cheers.

Comment: Ok Joel, thank U, i check it. yes my questions is not full, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JFrame, my suggestion is that you try something like this. First a main method that calls createAndShowGUI():

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        try {
            createAndShowGUI();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });
    }
```

Then you create JFrame structure:

```
static void createAndShowGUI() throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
    // Creates the window (JFrame)
    frame = new JFrame("Name of the window");//                                    
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Create and set up the content pane.
    new Interface();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(700, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);// centers the window in the screen
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Interface() is a constructor of a class I created, that uses frame as main window, and adds JPanels inside it, but you can do in many other ways.

I guess that what you want is to show a window, don't you? What it is not clear is if you want to use Swing components.

Comment: Yes your code is work. i need to pass to method setWindowShape(Window, Sahpe) a Window class, this method does not work but method setWindowOpacity(Window, float) work when i am using form this line code w=(Window)JFrame. w is a Window